# Fritzbox 7490 FritOS 07.21 Can more than 13 port forwarding enries be added for a specific host?

Tags: fritzbox

I have just acquired a FritzBox 7490 and am setting it up to do port forwarding to a specific machine (let us call it hostA) on my LAN.  I have entered 13 entries so far.  When I add additional entries, (more than 13) even though the entry is created under sharing for hostA, and then click apply, the entry does not appear under hostA but appears under the next host (let us call it hostB) in the list of hosts connected to the LAN.

On saving the FritzBox 7490 configuration file to a computer and inspecting the entries, the additional port forwarding entry is definitely incorrectly created for hostB and not hostA.

Adding port forwarding entries to the wrong host is surely a security bug?

So is it possible to add 14 or more port sharing entries for a host on a FritzBox?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be some indexing issue.  After submitting my question and going back the the FritzBox web interface, my session had timed out and I had to sign in again with the access password.  I was then able to add some more entries ... but after the 3rd one was added, the fourth one then got added to hostB again.

After deleting (as I thought I had done) the entry erroneously added to hostB I then left the "Port Sharing" page (went to Overview), then clicked back on Internet -> Permit Access and then on to "Port Sharing", then entry under hostB was still there which I thought I had deleted.  Anyways after deleting that. I was then able to add successfully add another entry for hostA with the "New Sharing" button.

So it appears that AVM do not intend that one should be able to enter more than 3 port sharing entries consecutively and one has to leave the Permit Access page, go to another page, then back to Permit Access and then add a further three entries.